Disable roomba on Meta.SE feature requests

Feature request: disable roomba on Meta.SE feature requests.
Motivation: keep track of which feature requests were disapproved by the community.
Example 1 (link to post), Example 2 (link to post), Example 3 (link to post), Example 4 (link to post).

